How to calculate the number of possible combinations of different suits when choosing 5 cards from a standard deck of 52? Without order/repetition
The above question is something I was thinking about during my probability class- it's not part of the class, or maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about this.

To be clear... are you talking about "Five clubs" vs "Four clubs and one heart" and so on... where "$\clubsuit\clubsuit\clubsuit\clubsuit\heartsuit$" is considered the same as "$\clubsuit\clubsuit\heartsuit\clubsuit\clubsuit$"?  Or are those considered different?  We are not keeping track of the rank of the cards, so we don't care if its an Ace vs King vs 5 etc?

The most common interpretations of your question, the context of the deck of cards is irrelevant.  We either have $4^5$ orders of five suit symbols (choose the "first" suit, choose the "second" suit, etc...) where order of suits matters seen by rule of product, or we have $\binom{5+4-1}{4-1}$ different collections of suits possible seen by stars-and-bars where order of suits doesn't matter.  The number $52$ is irrelevant beyond noting that we have more than 5 copies of each suit available.  (Of course, we must repeat a suit somehow here by pigeonhole)

What is the probability of each of the following occurring: 5-0-0-0, 4-1-0-0, 3-2-0-0, 3-1-1-0, 2-2-1-0, 2-1-1-1 ?  Note that since these distributions are the only ones possible, and since these distributions are all mutually exclusive, the sum of the probabilities must equal $~1.~$  So, re sanity-checking, if you make an analytical mistake, the total will probably not sum to $~1.~$

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

We start by finding a proper way to represent the combinations so we can easily count them. In this case we can see a possible combination as an ordered quadrupel $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, with $x_i$ the number of cards with suit $i$. This means we want to count all ordered combinations with $\sum_ix_i=5$
To make this easier we will break it down by the maximum of the 4 elements. This maximum can be 5, 4, 3 or 2:

Max 5 can only be the numbers {5, 0, 0, 0}
Max 4 can only be {4, 1, 0, 0}
Max 3 can be {3, 2, 0, 0} or {3, 1, 1, 0}
Max 2 can be {2, 2, 1, 0} or {2, 1, 1, 1}

We now need to count how many different ways there are to order these 6 possible distributions of suits. Each can be computed as the product of two binomial coefficients. This is because you first need to pick the spots that will be non-zero. And then out of the non-zero spots you need to pick the placement of one of the remaining (at the max) two numbers. This works out as follows:
{5, 0, 0, 0} : $\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{1}{1}=4$
{4, 1, 0, 0}: $\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{2}{1}=12$
{3, 2, 0, 0}: $\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{2}{1}=12$
{3, 1, 1, 0}: $\binom{4}{3}\times\binom{3}{1}=12$
{2, 2, 1, 0}: $\binom{4}{3}\times\binom{3}{2}=12$
{2, 1, 1, 1}: $\binom{4}{0}\times\binom{4}{1}=4$
For a total of 56 combinations.

Breaking into cases is an awful idea if you want to generalize the problem.  Note, your answer is equal to the $\binom{5+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{8}{3}=56$ alluded to in comments above corresponding to a direct (without messy casework) approach using a stars-and-bars argument.

@JMoravitz "Breaking into cases is an awful idea if you want to generalize the problem." : true but inconclusive, re the issue of what the most effective answer is here, for the specific target audience of this original poster.  Why burden the original poster with the added complexity of stretching their intuition around Stars and Bars?  I think that the task of intuitively grasping that the partition of $~5~$ into mutually exclusive cases is a valid approach, is a reasonably large first step for this original poster to take.  I then recommend that subsequent intuition stretching be deferred.
